# Is it possible to have a Subversion repository as a Git submodule?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Is there a way to add a Subversion repository as a Git submodule in my Git repository?

Something like:

```
git-svn submodule add https://svn.foo.com/svn/proj --stdlayout svn-project
```

Where `https://svn.foo.com/svn/proj` points to a Subversion repository.

I know there is `git-svn` which allows one to interact with a Subversion repository. So I am thinking, maybe there is a way to checkout a Subversion repository with `git-svn` and then use it as a submodule.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

No. Your best bet would be to set up a mirror of the svn repository in a dedicated git repository.

```
git svn clone -s http://subversion.example.com/ mysvnclone
cd mysvnclone
git remote add origin git@example.com:project.git
git push origin master
```

Then you can add the git repository as a submodule to the original project

```
cd /path/to/gitproject
git submodule add git://example.com/project.git -- svn-project
git add svn-project
git commit -m "Add submodule"
```

There is one conceptual difference between svn:externals and git submodule that may trip you up if you approach this from a subversion point of view. The git submodule is pegged to the revision that you give it. If "upstream" changes, then you have to update your submodule's reference.

So when we resync with the upstream subversion:

```
cd /path/to/mysvnclone
git svn rebase
git push
```

... the git project will still use the original revision that we committed earlier. To update to the svn HEAD, you would have to use

```
cd /path/to/gitproject/svn-project
git checkout master
git pull
cd ..
git add svn-project
git commit -m"Update submodule"
```

Comment: Have you tried these codes before post it to here? submodules can't work properly at git svn.

Comment: @xhan yes, and I am not advocating mixing git-svn and submodules in the same repository. The clone that uses git-svn is only a bridge to creating a native git clone of the svn repository.

Comment: sorry. I haven't found you using two folders to acts as submodules. nice trick.

Comment: Nice technique. Don't you need a 'git init --bare' step on the server, before pushing the git-svn repo there? I had to do this.

Comment: It's probably not the default but you can bind svn:externals to a specific revision just like git submodules do.

Comment: I get complaints (warning) about a missing --prefix flag for the first command. Should I care?

Comment: @bobbaluba have a look here http://blog.tfnico.com/2013/08/always-use-git-svn-with-prefix.html

Comment: If something ever happens to the original svn/git project, is it possible to rebuild it using git svn again?

Comment: @tofutim you have all the history (and svn metadata info) in your git svn copy, so yes in theory it would be possible. Haven't tried it though so YMMV :)

Comment: I discovered that when cloning from https://sourceforge.net/p/slam6d/code/HEAD/tree/ that removing the -s flag was needed to get svn to clone the actual repository.

Comment: @MatthewHoggan -s tells git-svn to use the "standard layout" that includes trunk, branches and *tags*. The respository you linked to doesn't use the traditional tags directory, so I think that's why it didn't work. Maybe you could pass in -b if you need the branches, or just nothing as you say, if all you need is trunk.

Answer (score 9):

I just went through this. I'm doing something similar to rq, but slightly different.
I setup one of my servers to host these git clones of the svn repos I need.  In my case I only want read-only versions, and need a bare repo on the server.

On the server I run:

```
GIT_DIR=<projectname>.git git init
cd <projectname>.git/
GIT_DIR=. git svn init svn://example.com/trunk
GIT_DIR=. git svn fetch
git gc
```

This sets up my bare repo, then I have a cron script to update it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, glob

GIT_HOME='/var/www/git'

os.chdir(GIT_HOME)
os.environ['GIT_DIR']='.'
gits = glob.glob('*.git')
for git in gits:
  if not os.path.isdir(git):
    continue
  os.chdir(os.path.join(GIT_HOME, git))
  if not os.path.isdir('svn/git-svn'):
    #Not a git-svn repo
    continue

  #Pull in svn updates
  os.system('git svn fetch && git gc --quiet')
  #fix-svn-refs.sh makes all the svn branches/tags pullable
  os.system('fix-svn-refs.sh')
  #Update the master branch
  os.system('git fetch . +svn/git-svn:master && git gc --quiet')`
```

This also requires fix-svn-refs.sh from http://www.shatow.net/fix-svn-refs.sh 
This was mostly inspired by: http://gsocblog.jsharpe.net/archives/12

I'm not sure why the `git gc` is needed here, but I wasn't able to do a `git pull` without it.

So after all this you can then use git submodule following rq's instructions.

Comment: One would think you could even do this as a commit hook.

Answer (score 6):

Currently *git-svn* doesn't support *svn:externals*. But there are two other tools which can help you:

1. [SubGit](http://subgit.com/)

   *SubGit* is server-side solution, it enables Git access to Subversion repository and vice versa.  You may refer to [documenation](http://subgit.com/howto/) for more details, but in general it is fairly easy to use SubGit:

   ```
   $ subgit configure --layout auto $SVN_URL $GIT_REPO
   ```

   Above command will detect branches layout in the SVN project and then will create empty bare Git repository ready to mirror SVN project. You may be asked for credentials unless those are already stored in the SVN credentials cache at ~/.subversion directory. You can also adjust `$GIT_REPO/subgit/authors.txt` to map SVN author names to Git identities.

   ```
   $ subgit install $GIT_REPO
   $ ... let initial translation complete ... 
   $ TRANSLATION SUCCESSFUL
   ```

   At this moment you have Subversion repository connected to newly created Git repository. SubGit translates SVN revision into Git commit on every `svn commit` and Git commit into SVN revision on every `git push`.

Everything you need further is to make Git repository available to committers. Take a look at [git-http-backend](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-http-backend.html) for that. Then you can add created Git repository as a usual submodule. 
 SubGit is also availale as an add-on for the Bitbucket Server, to find out more check out [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.tmatesoft.subgit.stash-svn-importer/server/overview).
 So, there is no need to use any external tools like *git-svn* or any other.

SubGit is proprietary software but it's free for small companies (up to 10 committers), academic and open-source projects.

2. [SmartGit](http://syntevo.com/smartgit/)

   SmartGit replaces *git-svn* on client-side. More information on its features you may find [here](http://www.syntevo.com/git-svn/features.html).

   In particular SmartGit does support both *git submodules* and *svn:externals*, you can mix them in your repository.

   SmartGit is proprietary software but it's free for non-commercial usage.

Comment: Both the `subgit` (https://subgit.com/documentation/config-options.html#translate.externals) and the `smartgit` supports the `svn:externals` in the same way by an explicit `.gitsvnextmodules` file in a working copy. Which means you still have to use these software to checkout externals and you can not use basic `git` utility to checkout those externals directly from an external git hub server like `github` or `gitlab`. So the sources releated to an `snv:externals` on an external git hub server won't be observable and downloadable without these software which is still a significant issue.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what rq said, another method would be to use the third-party "externals" project (http://nopugs.com/ext-tutorial), which better mimics how svn external references work. With externals you can track either git or svn repositories, and it looks easier to push your changes upstream to those repos. However, it requires project members to download and install the separate package.

I haven't used submodules or externals yet; however, I've spent a few hours reading about all alternatives and it looks like externals will be a better fit for my needs. There is an excellent discussion about these and other custom methods in Chapter 15 of "Version Control with Git", by Jon Loeliger (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520120), which I strongly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Piston is being rewritten to support this, and the converse, plus the existing Subversion URL in a Subvresion repoistory and git+git.

Check out [the piston Github repository](http://github.com/francois/piston/tree/master).

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have been released.

Comment: Piston will fail in your face when you need it the most though ;), so I don't recommend that. Plus there aren't any bugfixes for piston anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is `git-remote-testsvn`, so I guess something like

```
git submodule add testsvn::http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/bzquips/trunk/ \
    module/bzquips
```

should work. Does it?