# Tips on using Git with svn in presence of a large number of svn externals

Tags: django, svn, git, git-svn

I have a workflow(on svn) which I am trying to replicate with git, but am unable to.

I have a large number of Django apps (which are plugged together to form a form a full project) Some of these are in one large repo and others are in smaller repos.

My layout looks something like,

```
app1 -> repo1/app1
app2 -> repo2/app2
app3 -> repo1/appp3

templates/app1 -> repo1/templates/app1
templates/app2 -> repo2/app2/templates/app2
templates/app3 -> repo1/templates/appp3

site_media/app1 -> repo1/media/app1
site_media/app2 -> repo2/static/app2
site_media/app3 -> repo1/media/appp3
```

So I work in the correct app repos, and when we want to update any given project, we just do a svn up and svn exterbal takes care of the rest. How do I get this workflow in Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use git [submodules](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-submodule.html), and [this prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465042/is-it-possible-to-have-a-subversion-repository-as-a-git-submodule) addressed integrating svn repos into a git project.

Answer (score 0):

You may clone your SVN repository with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) to get Git repostiory with .gitsvnextmodules file generated. SmartGit will display all your submodules and clone (you may control how deep) them to local Git repositories too. So you'll get the same structure and workflow but Git-based.