# Git submodule not updating from a git-svn repository

Tags: git, git-svn, git-submodules

I have a projectx which includes a git submodule

```
/projectx/foo/bar/submodule
```

The submodule repository is itself a git-svn repo which tracks an svn repository.

In the standalone submodule repo, I've pulled in some new updates:

```
git svn fetch
```

and I see some revisions come in. So I run:

```
git svn rebase master
```

and when I call:

```
git status
```

It all looks fine. So in the root of my projectx I run:

```
git submodule update
```

and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I've definitely run:

```
git submodule add
git submodule init
```

on the submodule, and when I run:

```
git submodule status
```

I see the hash for its status.

So why does `git submodule update` not cause any update to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `git submodule update` causes a `git fetch` to be run in the submodule rather than `git svn fetch`.  The easiest solution is to keep your `git-svn` clone of the subversion repository elsewhere, and then add *that* repository as a submodule.  That is the suggestion in this similar question:

- [Is it possible to have a Subversion repository as a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/465042/223092)

Presumably if you want anyone else to use your repository, that's what you'd want to do anyway, since `.gitmodules` can only point to a git repository, not an SVN repository.

Of course, nothing stops you from just manually running a `git svn rebase` in your submodule directory and then adding and committing whatever version you like in the supermodule.  However, the URL in `.gitmodules` will need to point to that repository, or a clone of it.

Comment: _The easiest solution is to keep your git-svn clone of the subversion repository elsewhere, and then add that repository as a submodule._ - yep, that's what I've done... but your mention of **git svn rebase** in the submodule put me on the right track. I just needed to **git pull origin master** in the submodule. I was getting it all arse backwards and thought the git submodule update would update the local submodule and cause a fetch/merge to happen. Thanks!