# Adding SVN library to a git repository. Hints? Tips? Do I need to make a submodule for it?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository, git-submodules

I'm making an iOS app which is in a git repository. I'd like to add the Google Objective C client library, but it's stored via SVN. What's the recommended way to add an SVN project to a git repository? Do I need to make a submodule for it or is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at this:

[Is it possible to have a subversion repository as a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465042/is-it-possible-to-have-a-subversion-repository-as-a-git-submodule)

Also, you may consider the easy route and just copying the source at the revision you want into your own repo. Some may not consider this "best practice" but makes maintenance simple.