# How to manage external libraries in Xcode/git source control?

Tags: xcode, git, google-cloud-endpoints

Okay, I'm trying to add Endpoints for Google App Engine to my app project.

The directions for the iOS client code say to download this svn project:

```
svn checkout \
    http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ \
    google-api-objectivec-client-read-only
```

and [then](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Linking_to_the_iOS_Static_Library)

> The static library target should be dragged into your application project's Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" list.

As I understand it, for that to be possible, I should be basically following [Apple's directions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH1-SW1) for static library child projects.

But now the Google code is not in my git repository, so when I attempt to clone my project to work on a different branch, it's not included and doesn't come along.  And I can't add it to my project without causing an svn error.

What do I do about this?   I could do a recursive copy of the code out of the svn working copy and explicitly check it into my git repository, but then it seems like updating to any future versions of that project from Google will be a nightmare.  Or are child projects just a bad idea?  I've never had good luck with Xcode trying to compile a separate static library and including the binary in my main project -- is that what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can do this trick to create a git copy of the svn repository, then create a submodule from the git copy:

[Is it possible to have a Subversion repository as a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465042/is-it-possible-to-have-a-subversion-repository-as-a-git-submodule)