# Is there anyway to clone one particular folder from SVN repository to git

Tags: git, svn

Our team have a remote git repository located in US.and we have our source code stored in SVN.

Which is the best way to share our code.I do not want to clone my entire svn repository to git or vice versa

Can I point my SVN repository to get source code from the Git remote Repository so that we will not store source code from git repository to our SVN server?

Any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I point my SVN repository to get source code from the Git remote Repository

In short - no. Git can read|write into SVN-repos, but inversed "driver" isn't possible

But title of your question describe slightly different case - you want (?) to have part of SVN repository  (trunk?) in Git with bi-directional sync? And this trick is possible, rather easy - clone with [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_basic_examples) or SubGit `REPO/trunk`, get ordinary git-repository with one know remote (SVN repo), which can be used in casual way, and data can be exchanged with SVN

Comment: I will explain little more detail . We have a git Repository in US (This contains around 20 or 30 gigabytes of Data). We have an SVN repository in our office(Which have around 2 or 3 gigabytes of data) .I  do not want to store their data in our repository or they do not want to store our data. What I need is a mechanism without cloning the actual data just like SVN:externals.

Comment: @technooracle - SVN (is|must) be part of Git-tree, and combined tree have to appear only at US-side. Correct?

Comment: @technooracle - some old links JFYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571232/svnexternals-equivalent-in-git http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132174/how-to-use-subversion-repository-inside-git-repository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465042/is-it-possible-to-have-a-subversion-repository-as-a-git-submodule and not tried yet, but promising http://danielcestari.com/git-external/